# Combine prisms to focus on a value regardless of a branch

Tags: purescript, lenses

I have a sum type of possible outcomes, and in every outcome there is a certain "Result" that I want to focus on. I know how to get that "Result" from each of the outcomes (I have a bunch of prisms for that), but I don't know how to combine these prisms so that I can grab the "Result" from the whole sumtype, without worrying which case I'm on.

Simplified example:

```hs
type OneAnother = Either Int Int

exampleOneAnother :: OneAnother
exampleOneAnother = Left 10

_one :: Prism' OneAnother Int
_one = _Left

_another :: Prism' OneAnother Int
_another = _Right

_result :: Lens' OneAnother Int
_result = ???
-- How can I combine _one and _another to get result regardless whether its left or right ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a prism comes to focus, it loses the context. So I don't see a way to define `_result` in terms of `_one` and `_another`. But you can certainly do better than resorting to `unsafePartial`:

```hs
import Data.Lens.Lens (Lens', lens)
import Data.Profunctor.Choice ((|||), (+++))

type OneAnother = Either Int Int

_result :: Lens' OneAnother Int
_result = lens getter setter
  where
  getter      = identity ||| identity
  setter e x  = (const x +++ const x) e
```

---

Stole this from the [`profunctor-lens`](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-profunctor-lenses/blob/master/src/Data/Lens/Lens.purs#L70) repository:

```hs
-- | Converts a lens into the form that `lens'` accepts.
lensStore :: forall s t a b . ALens s t a b -> s -> Tuple a (b -> t)
lensStore l = withLens l (lift2 Tuple)
```

It isn't exported somehow. With that help, the following solution should be generic enough:

```hs
import Prelude
import Control.Apply (lift2)
import Data.Lens.Common
import Data.Lens.Lens
import Data.Lens.Prism
import Data.Profunctor.Choice ((|||), (+++))
import Data.Tuple

_result :: Lens' OneAnother Int
_result = lens getter setter
  where
  getter      = identity ||| identity
  setter e x  = (const x +++ const x) e

lensStore :: forall s t a b . ALens s t a b -> s -> Tuple a (b -> t)
lensStore l = withLens l (lift2 Tuple)

data ABC
  = A Int
  | B (Tuple Boolean Int)
  | C OneAnother

lensABCInt :: Lens' ABC Int
lensABCInt = lens' case _ of
  A i -> map A <$> lensStore identity i
  B i -> map B <$> lensStore _2 i
  C i -> map C <$> lensStore _result i
```

Here `ABC` is your target sum type. As long as its each variant has a lens, you have a lens for it as a whole.

Comment: This for sure looks better, but it is tied to Either. In reality I have a different sum type with more than 2 alternatives. I don't think I can compose them with ||| and +++ as easily. But that's an interesting direction to look at. Thanks.

Comment: @MnZrK answer expanded.

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've got so far. Yes, `unsafePartial`, explicit case matching ... Really hope there is something better.

```hs
_result :: Lens' OneAnother Int
_result = lens getter setter
  where
  getter :: OneAnother -> Int
  getter x@(Left _) = unsafePartial $ fromJust $ preview _one x

  getter x@(Right _) = unsafePartial $ fromJust $ preview _another x

  setter :: OneAnother -> Int -> OneAnother
  setter (Left _) x = review _one x

  setter (Right _) x = review _another x
```